# Prove that $108^3-7^3$ is a multiple of $101$

Tags: arithmetic

Encountered the next problem: prove that $108^3-7^3$ is the multiple to $101$.

As I understand if $c$ is the multiple to $a$ it means that there exist $b\in\mathbb{N}$ that $ab=c$. So i want to factor out $101$ from the expression, and I don't see a way to do it. I will appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Do you know about congruence modulo $n$?

Comment: $108^3-7^3=(108-7)(108^2+108\times 7+7^2)$

Comment: $108\equiv7\bmod101$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks. Now it seems so obvious!

Comment: Also check out egreg's method. It is more general than this solution :).

Answer (score 3):

Use the properties of congruences, so you don't have to do any factorization.

Since $108\equiv 7\pmod{101}$, you have
$$
108^3\equiv7^3\pmod{101}
$$
which is the same as saying that $108^3-7^3$ is a multiple of $101$.

Comment: thx, for showing this. Have just red about it - learnt something new :-)

Comment: Can you say the law that allows to elevate to 3 a congruence?

Comment: @JoséOsorio If $a\equiv b\pmod{k}$ and $c\equiv d\pmod{k}$, then $ac\equiv bd\pmod{k}$.